# Custom Annotation using JSR 3.0

Tags: spring-boot, jsr

I have one pojo class with name LoanForm with few fields:`String loanType;String source;String amount;`

I created a custom annotation for loanType. Below is the code.Next I created another class as validator LoanTypeConstraintValidator. Below is the code.The above annotation is checking if loantype is blank or not. I have 3 sources let's say A,B,C. Now if source is A and user submits the form an error message will get display. But if source is B even if loanType is null or blank form should get submitted. So I am stuck at how to access source field in this LoanType custom annotation and how to check if source is A or B or C.

Here is my Custom Validator class code:

```
 public class LoanTypeConstraintValidator
            implements ConstraintValidator<LoanType, Integer>
    {
        public void initialize(LoanType loanType)
        {
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isValid(Integer loanTypeField, ConstraintValidatorContext arg1)
        {
            if (loanTypeField == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Custom Annotation class:

Comment: Custom Validator class code:                                                                                                       public class LoanTypeConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<LoanType, Integer> {

 public void initialize(LoanType loanType) {
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isValid(Integer loanTypeField, ConstraintValidatorContext arg1) {
  if (loanTypeField == null) {
   return true;
  }

  else {
   return false;
  }
 }
 
 
}